# Inserting LilyPond files into ShareLatex

Tags: external-files, sharelatex, music, lilypond

I've created a couple LilyPond .ly files, with some music I want to insert into a Latex document I have on ShareLatex, but I don't know which packages to use etc.

Does anyone know how I can get this done?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you read [Lilypond's documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.17/Documentation/usage/latex.en.html)? If yes, could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates where exactly is your problem? You can also browse [lilypond related questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lilypond) to help you.

Comment: IN general, to insert lilypond music into LaTeX, you can either create images (e.g. in .png format) from Lilypond  and `\includegraphics` in LaTeX, or use Lilypond-book. The "best" choice depends what you want to do - for example, if the music needs two systems, do you want one at the bottom of a page and the second at the top of the next page, or both on the same page? I don't know anything about ShareLatex, so this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: If you're restricted to working with ShareLatex, I recommend creating the individual LilyPond images (I recommend .pdf because they're smaller and higher quality) and using `\includegraphics`. Going the `lilypond-book` route requires some command-line work that, if it's even possible on ShareLatex, seems needlessly complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with just creating individual images (`.pdf`, with the highest quality option, as @Richard suggested) and inserting them into the `.tex` with `\includegraphics`. It's not a perfect solution, but it was definitely good enough for my purposes.

As an aside, using ShareLaTeX (now Overleaf) is a good solution when you're relatively new to LaTeX, but situations like this where it forces you to use suboptimal workarounds do arise quite often. I now use TeXStudio and don't think I'll ever need another LaTeX editor again.