# Generate a musical note on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, lilypond, abc

How can I write music sheet on Overleaf? I am trying to generate a single "A1" note as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Seems there is only one template on overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/music and that uses m-tx (PMX language)? you could ask overleaf to consider lilypond enhancements anyway have you tried https://www.hacklily.org/ OLD thread for lilypond to Overleaf (sharelatex) is here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370643/inserting-lilypond-files-into-sharelatex

Comment: _Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf._ Lilypond isn't currently supported on Overleaf at the moment; sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO you should not use LaTeX to deal with music. (What am I saying :)) Anyway, MusiXTeX is the best option right now, but its macros are really hard to learn. It is written mainly for plain TeX.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
\setclef1{6}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}}
\startextract
\Notes\wh A\off{7\noteskip}\en\setdoubleBAR
\endextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope a package for music in LaTeX, which is easy to use, will be released soon.

Comment: What does your last comment mean? Music typesetting is complex, so 'easy to use' will always be relative. For a purely TeX system, `musixtex` is remarkable and not too difficult to use.

Comment: @AlanMunn It is opinion-based. Maybe I find it a bit difficult because I am not familiar with plain TeX.

Comment: m-tx provides an easier syntax to use musixtex: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/polyphonic-or-instrumental-music-with-m-tx-and-musixtex-on-overleaf/whwddhhnggnx

Comment: @LianTzeLim Oh, it looks so simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to test midi music on the web there is a site that allows you to test lilypond notation so for example cut and paste this MWE sample into https://www.hacklily.org/ where you can hear online or download the midi.
To see more on how Lilypond notation is then converted to TeX see http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/latex

[image]

```
\header {
  title = "Rodrigo's Tune"
  composer = "KJO"
}
\score {
 \relative c,{
\numericTimeSignature
\time 4/4
 \clef bass
   a1 b2 a4 a8 b8
   }
   \layout {}
  \midi {}
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't think it's really an answer to the question.

Comment: @AlanMunn I know but similar to other suggestions as to using mathjax etc it is an online alternative to generate the \include lilypond contents for final TeX production

Comment: Sure, but can you show how you would use the site to generate the fragment of music in the question?

Comment: @AlanMunn Ok have changed it to include the one bar per question but could not resist adding another to show how easy to add the next 4 seconds. It's over 50 years since I was allowed to hit a triangle, especially since my music teacher likened my musical ear and singing to an "upstart crow" which I considered a compliment until I found out they were very derisory about the English Lit teachers